# C++ Reading UTF-8 file OK, converting to UTF-16 OK, writing back to file NOT OK

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, unicode

I'm using the following code to read from a text (.xml) file I have created in a text editor (Notepad++), convert the UTF-8 text I read from it into UTF-16 so that Windows API functions can use it, and then write this UTF-16 encoded text back into a second file.

My problem is that when I open the output file in Notepad++, I don't get what I'm expecting to see, no matter what encoding I ask the text editor to use. There are null characters before almost every character in the file. I assume that either I did something wrong while writing the UTF-16 to the output file or Notepad++ is reading as single byte chars.

Any idea please? Here is the code:

```
#define UNICODE

// includes...

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * pzInFile,
         * pzOutFile;

    try
    {
        char   sUtf8[8192];
        char * pcDst = sUtf8;

        wchar_t wsUtf16[8192];

        _wfopen_s( & pzInFile, L"../config-sample.xml", L"r" );
        _wfopen_s( & pzOutFile, L"../config-sample2.xml", L"w+" );

        if( pzInFile && pzOutFile )
        {
            size_t uiRead;

            while( uiRead = fread_s( pcDst, sizeof( sUtf8 ), 1, 1, pzInFile ) )
            {
                pcDst += uiRead;
            }

            size_t uiLen = pcDst - sUtf8;

            sUtf8[uiLen] = 0;

            MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, sUtf8, 8192, wsUtf16, 8192 ); // UTF-8 to UTF-16

            fwrite( wsUtf16, 1, uiLen, pzOutFile );
        }
        else
        {
            throw L"Failed to open file";
        }
    }
    catch( const wchar_t * pwsMsg )
    {
        ::MessageBox( NULL, pwsMsg, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST | MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    }

    if( pzInFile )
    {
        fclose( pzInFile );
        pzInFile = 0;
    }
    if( pzOutFile )
    {
        fclose( pzOutFile );
        pzOutFile = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like Notepad++ doesn't actually "understand" UTF-16 characters (or is not "detecting" it properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code to fix a few errors.  Notepad++ was displaying the output files correctly with or without a BOM, so its detection routines for the encoding seem sound.

The main issues were:

- The output file (at least) needs to be opened in binary mode or two-byte UTF-16 characters with `0A` in them will get translated on Windows to `0D 0A`.
- I simplified the file read to fill the buffer in one read and accounted for the null termination to be added.
- `MultibyteToWideChar` returns the number of characters converted and I used `-1` for the input buffer size since it was null-terminated.
- `fwrite` needs to write the converted characters (minus the null) with the correct byte count for the converted string.  A character is two bytes in UTF-16.

As for your file corruption, originally the `fwrite` was writing bytes equal to the UTF-8 string length.  Since that is 1-3 characters the original output file length I got was 39 bytes...impossible for a UTF-16 file so perhaps Notepad++'s encoding heuristic didn't detect UTF-16.  Since you didn't provide sample data I made up some and my Notepad++ still detected UTF-16, so the heuristic may guess depending on the data as well.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* pzInFile;
    FILE* pzOutFile;

    try
    {
        char    sUtf8[8192];
        wchar_t wsUtf16[8192];

        _wfopen_s(& pzInFile, L"config-sample.xml", L"r");
        _wfopen_s(& pzOutFile, L"config-sample2.xml", L"w+b");

        if(pzInFile && pzOutFile)
        {
            size_t uiRead = fread_s(sUtf8, sizeof(sUtf8), 1, sizeof(sUtf8) - 1, pzInFile);
            sUtf8[uiRead] = 0;

            int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, sUtf8, -1, wsUtf16, 8192);   // UTF-8 to UTF-16

            fwrite(wsUtf16, 1, (wlen-1) * sizeof(wchar_t), pzOutFile);
        }
        else
        {
            throw L"Failed to open file";
        }
    }
    catch(const wchar_t* pwsMsg)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, pwsMsg, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
    }

    if(pzInFile)
    {
        fclose(pzInFile);
        pzInFile = 0;
    }
    if(pzOutFile)
    {
        fclose(pzOutFile);
        pzOutFile = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My data file contained:

```
<data>αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ</data>
```

Here is the input and output files' hex dumps.  Note that on input since I left the input file opening in text mode the `0D0A` CR-LF combination was translated to just `0A`, so only the linefeed ended up in the binary mode output file.  I left that to illustrate the Windows text vs. binary issue.  You should probably open both in binary mode.

```
input:  3C646174613ECEB1C39FCE93CF80CEA3CF83C2B5CF84CEA6CE98CEA9CEB43C2F646174613E0D0A0D0A
output: 3C0064006100740061003E00B103DF009303C003A303C303B500C403A6039803A903B4033C002F0064006100740061003E000A000A00
```

Answer (score 2):

For UTF-16-encoded text files, you should write out a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the start of the file so that any program reading the file knows if the file is little-endian (UTF-16LE) or big-endian (UTF-16BE).  If a text file doesn't begin with either the two bytes `FF FE` or `FE FF`, then most programs assume that the file was written with a single-byte encoding (e.g. UTF-8 or Windows-1252).

One way to do that would be like so:

```
wchar_t bom = 0xFEFF;
fwrite(&bom, 1, sizeof(bom), pzOutFile);
fwrite(wsUtf16, 1, uiLen, pzOutFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is an improvement : no more null characters everywhere, but not half of the characters are asian signs, so i guess there is another thing to do ? I also tried FFFE, but i also got an ugly result. By the way, does it make any difference to do `fwrite(&bom, 1, sizeof(bom), pzOutFile);` instead of `fwrite(&bom, sizeof(bom), 1, pzOutFile);`?

Comment: Or maybe that it's because i'm making Notepad++ read as UCS-2 which i assumed to be UTF-16 ?

Comment: @Virus721: They're subtly different, especially for asian characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you're writing UTF-16 to a file that's being read as UTF-8 -- hence the null characters before every character.  You simply want to to write back your UTF-16 converted to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the logic of Notepad++ is for detecting UTF-16 (if it can at all), but it's quite like that you need a "byteorder mark" of `0xFFEF` before your actual UTF-16 content.